# How can I clear the output portion of the Command Center.?

Tags: netlogo

Is there a command to clear the output portion of the Command Center?   I can't find one in the user-guide -- only commands to clear a separate output area if one was defined.

I'm using NetLogo 6.1.1. in Windows 10.

I don't have a separate output section defined. The command "clear-output" doesn't clear the output portion of the Command Center.

I tried making a separate output section on the interface, and print-output and clear-output work fine on it.  But without a separate area, print-output goes to the command center but clear-output doesn't clear it.

Manually pushing the "clear" button on the interface does clear it.

Am I missing something obvious?

Manually entering these commands in the command center does not clear it:

```
print "x"
clear-output
```

Doing it from inside code doesn't seem to work either

```
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if (ticks > 4) [stop]
  print ( word "line one at tick " ticks)
  if (ticks > 3 ) [clear-output]
  tick
end
```

Comment: I'm not going to do this as an answer because I am not completely confident, but I don't believe there is a way to clear this except using the button. If you are wanting program control over the output, then the intent is to use an output area. That output area can also be exported.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "you can not". You can put an "Output" on the interface tab and use `output-print` instead of `print`. This way `clear-output` works perfectly.